# Download Jasper report instead of opening in browser

Tags: jsf, jasper-reports

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 and JSF 2.2

Following is my code: I am generating `PDF` file from `TableModelDate` method all works fine. But it is opening in my browser How can i download it without opening.

```
public void PDF() throws JRException, IOException {
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    simpleReport();
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=report.pdf");
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,servletOutputStream);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}

public void simpleReport() {
    TableModelData();
    try {
        String reportPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/reports/");
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(reportPath+"/Report.jrxml");
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath+"/Report.jasper", new HashMap(),new JRTableModelDataSource(tableModel));
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close to it.

just add `attachment;` statement with the `filename=xx.pdf`
Like:

```
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
```

It tells Http Servlet Responce that the file contains is attachment;

**Extra:**

Whenever browser opens `PDF` format it also shows saving option you can also save it after opening(loading) in browser